# How can I fill in a foreign key value after creating the first entry of the table the foreign key is referencing?

Tags: database-design, schema, sqlite

I am seeking to create an online store so I got to the database definition. I want to have as few tables as possible, so I've got them narrowed down to:

1. Users
2. Products
3. Orders
4. Cart_Items

I got to the following schema: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfbuE.png)

The logic flows like this: For each product added in the cart, a new Cart_Item entry is created. But the Cart_Item entry needs to fill in the foreign key that references the Order table, which is cartItemOrderID. Since there's no order created, it'll have to be null at first. Once the user adds all their desired items in the cart, they place the order, and a new Order is created, so now I have the orderID. How would I pass this orderID to the entries in the Cart_Item table, since there's no way to tell they were placed by the current user?

I'm missing something huge but I can't put my finger on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your main challenge is the requirement that the `Order` is in between your `User` and `Cart_Item`.

I am assuming you are planning on storing items put in the shopping cart in `Cart_Item` (items planned to be purchased but not currently purchased.  Also there is only 1 list of items pending purchase per user).  And then items actually purchased by the user (coming from he shopping cart) will land in `Order`.  In my opinion, there should not be any kind of link between the "order" and the "shopping cart".  If there was, you would need to store some kind of `Cart_ItemId` on the `Order` table, not an `orderId` on `Cart_Item`.  If you were to keep a `Cart_ItemId`, you would then have to have some kind of shopping cart history, which to me, seems redundant since that data would be saved in your "order history" though `Order`. You may have another purpose that I am not thinking of so let me know if I am missing something.

Assuming my understanding of what you are looking for is correct.  I believe this below schema is much closer to giving you what you are looking for, and getting you around this `Foreign Key` issue. (I apologize, your relationship diagram was so much nicer than mine.  Trying to make it work in Visio instead):

[image: Schema Recommendation]

Transferring data from your Cart to Your Order could look something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [FinalizeOrder] (@UserID INT, @OrderDetails VarChar(500))
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Order_Item
    (
        userID,
        orderProductId,
        quantity,
        price,
        [date],
        details
    )
    SELECT
    CI.userID,  --userID,
    CI.cartItemProductID,   --orderProductId,
    CI.quantity,    --quantity,
    P.price,    --price,
    GETDATE(),  --[date],
    @OrderDetails --details
    FROM Cart_Item CI
        INNER JOIN Product P
            ON CI.cartItemProductID = P.ProductId
    WHERE CI.userID = @UserID

    DELETE FROM Cart_Item
    WHERE CI.userID = @UserID
END
```

Now if it was me, I would create `Order` and `OrderItems` tables.  That way you don't duplicate data like the User, or address information on each item.  I know you want to limit tables that are created, but I think that will help you a lot.  If that is a route you end up going, than you will have a schema a little like this:

[image: Schema Recommendation]

For a quick example.  Lets pretend I am a user (UserID 13 because that is my favorite number).  I fill out a cart with the 5 items.  The records from the `Cart_Item` table looks like:

```
+------------+--------+-------------------+----------+
| CartItemId | UserID | CartItemProductID | quantity |
+------------+--------+-------------------+----------+
|          1 |     13 |               123 |        1 |
|          2 |     13 |               456 |        2 |
|          3 |     13 |               789 |        5 |
|          4 |     13 |            123456 |       77 |
|          5 |     13 |                56 |       45 |
+------------+--------+-------------------+----------+
```

When I hit the last "submit" in the check out process we would then write 1 record to `Order` and 5 rows to `Order_Item`.  Those rows would look something like:

```
[ORDER]
+----------+--------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| OrderId  | UserId |   Date   |                        Details                         |
+----------+--------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| 98564745 |     13 | 4/6/2020 | Order Placed by Kirk Saunders on 4/6/2020 for 5 items. |
+----------+--------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+

[ORDER_ITEM]
+----------+--------------------+----------+-------+
| OrderID  | OrderItemProductID | Quantity | Price |
+----------+--------------------+----------+-------+
| 98564745 |                123 |        1 |     1 |
| 98564745 |                456 |        2 |   1.5 |
| 98564745 |                789 |        5 |  7.98 |
| 98564745 |             123456 |       77 | 85.99 |
| 98564745 |                 56 |       45 |  1065 |
+----------+--------------------+----------+-------+
```

A Stored Procedure to handle this might look like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [FinalizeOrder] (@UserID INT, @OrderDetails VarChar(500))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @OrderId INT

    INSERT INTO [Order]
    (
        userID,
        [date],
        details
    )
    VALUES
    (
        @userID,    --userID,
        GETDATE(),  --[date],
        @OrderDetails --details
    )

    SET @OrderId = scope_identity()

    INSERT INTO Order_Item
    (
        OrderId,
        OrderItemProductID,
        Quantity,
        Price
    )
    @OrderId,   --OrderId,
    CI.cartItemProductID,   --OrderItemProductID,
    CI.Quantity,    --Quantity,
    P.Price --Price
    FROM Cart_Item CI
        INNER JOIN Product P
            ON CI.cartItemProductID = P.ProductId
    WHERE CI.userID = @UserID

    DELETE FROM Cart_Item
    WHERE CI.userID = @UserID
END
```

Hopefully this helps.  Let me know if I need to explain something better or if this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. My thoughts:
You said a user can only have one Cart_Item. If a user placed an order, and an order can contain multiple Cart_Item, then I suppose an user can still have access to multiple items.
And, yes, my logic initially meant that Cart_Item entries would lead to Order entries, that was the problem initially, because I had Cart_Item entries, but I had no Order they could refer to.

Comment: Regarding the model you proposed: What exactly is the table Order_Item? When would you add an entry to this table?
Also, how would the logic work if there was no direct relationship between Cart_Item entries and Order entries?

Comment: @Radu, I apologize if my answer was confusing.  I will certainly change the wording in the answer to make it more understandable.  When I made the comment about a user only has one cart, I was referring to how when someone it utilizing this platform.  I am assuming there will only be one list of items which they are planning on purchasing.  I see this as different in your original version, since the cart was tied to the order.  Which i my mind meant that you would effectively be keeping a "cart history" in the `Cart_Item` table.  That may not be been what you meant, but that is what I read.

Comment: @Radu.  The intent of the `Order_Item` table is to hold the items associated with a given order.  When the user finishes the order process.  One record would be written to `Order` which holds things like the shipping address, the date the order was placed, etc.  Then each item that was on that order will be written to `Order_Item`.  That way things like: the user who placed the order, when the order was placed, the address it would be shipped to, etc... is not repeated on for each product.  But that may be more normalization than you want.  That is just how we handle orders at my work.

Comment: It was my bad, I did not explain good enough. The Cart_Item table contains rows of Products in a User's cart. Once the order is placed, the Cart_Item table would become empty. That's why it was tied to the Order table, it would read as "One Order has one-or-multiple Cart_Items" (meaning a single order has one, or multiple chosen products). I do not want to keep a history of the carts, once a cart is bought, the info should get archived to the Order table. So let's say the Cart_Item table will be cut off (because it seems it has the same functionality as Order_Item in your example). Then..

Comment: ... what you're suggesting is that once a user goes to a product and adds it to the cart, a new entry in the Order_Item table gets added with said product. Add as many as you like, and then when the user clicks "Place order", a new entry in Order is created, and the orderID is passed to all the products previously on the cart, correct?

Comment: @Radu.  Is there a particular reason you want to have a relationship between the order and the cart?  I think that may be where you and I are missing each other.  We both agree that data in the cart should get transferred to the order once it is completed.  We just don't seem to agree on the need for a direct relationship (a `foreign key`) between the two tables.

Comment: Is it somehow possible to transfer the data from the Cart and the Order table without there being a direct relationship between them? I think this is the question that led me to think a direct relationship between the two was necessary.

Comment: @Radu.  To transfer data between the two tables you don't need to have a relationship.  You would use a relationship if you needed to make sure some kind of "parent-child" relationship is in place.  IE: Not allowing a `ProductID` to be written to either `Cart_Item` or `Order`/`Order_Item` that doesn't actually exist.  Let me update my answer with some code to show you how you could transfer the data between the two tables without a relationship.

Comment: @Radu, I have updated the answer with two different small `Stored Procedures`.  Let me know if there are any other questions.  Hopefully this gets to what you are needing.

Comment: Thank you, Kirk. You have been most helpful. I need to brush up a bit on my Stored Procedures knowledge, but now that I know that transferring information outside directly-related tables is possible, I can attempt this. You have also cleared up the table structure in a way that is very clean and easy to understand, your example helped a lot.